# Setting text widget / html widget for feature form using pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis

I want to add an html widget / text widget to my feature form using pyqgis.
The below image shows what oi want to achieve:
[image]

This is what I hvae tried so far:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

editFormConfig = layer.editFormConfig()
editFormConfig.setWidgetConfig(
    'TextEdit'
)
layer.setEditFormConfig(editFormConfig)
```

I dont know the exact way to use this function.